# How is shift-enter represented in a Word doc?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm using Java and Apache POI to read a Word documen template and generate a new document from it. The original document has newline breaks entered with "shift-enter"; I thought it would allow a line break while continuing the paragraph. But as I sequence through runs, I seem to get an empty string at that point. There are 'flags' on the run; do they indicate the line break somehow? I want to leave it in the resuling document; I think what's happening is that I detect it as an empty string and leave it out. How can I detect its presence so I can leave it in the resulting document after I've processed the template?

As a side note, are those flags documented anywhere?

Comment: [1] Re the question in your title, see [Name of formatting symbol for shift+enter](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/name-of-formatting-symbol-for-shiftenter/83a3f3fc-8bfe-4db7-b5ca-30613905e127) [2] You are asking four distinct questions. They are all obviously related, but you might consider rewording your question to make it a bit more focused/coherent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are talking about `XWPF` of `apache poi` which is the `apache poi` part to handle Office Open XML file format `*.docx`.

All [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) file formats are ZIP archives containing XML files and other files in a special directory structure. So one can simply unzip a `*.docx` file and have a look into it.

For an explicit line break (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) you will find following XML in `/word/document.xml` in that ZIP archive:

```
...
<w:r ...>
 <w:br/>
</w:r>
...
```

So it is a run element (`w:r`) containing one or more break elements (`w:br`).

The run element (`w:r`) is the low level source for a [XWPFRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html) in `apache poi`. It is represented by a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR` which can be got via `XWPFRun.getCTR`.

So if you got a `XWPFRun run`, you can get the explicit line breaks as so:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < run.getCTR().getBrList().size(); i++) {
 System.out.println("<BR />");
}
...
```

Is this documented anywhere?

There is [ECMA-376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/) for Office Open XML.

The `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes are auto-generated from this specifications. Unfortunately  there is not a API documentation public available. So one needs downloading the sources from [ooxml-schemas](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas) (up to `apache poi 4`) or [poi-ooxml-full](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-full) (from `apache poi 5` on) and then doing `javadoc` from them.

Comment: That's very helpful. It appears the getBrList() call gives a list of breaks; are they all of the shift-enter sort, or are there other kinds? And are they always at the end of the run, or can they be spread through text in the middle of the run?

Comment: I found a way to handle things for my particular problem -- I take a 'template paragraph' and clone it and the runs in it. In the method that clones the runs, I added lines to look for a non-empty array of breaks; if I find one, I copy it to the cloned run along with other things I don't understand. It's working so far. Thanks again.